# How to get public information available on a facebook page

Tags: facebook, public

When I am trying to subscribe a page to my facebook application, the application is asking for manage_pages permission. I am sending a post request to /{page-id}/subscribed_apps.

I am looking for a way to subscribe to a page and configure webhook for only public page information without asking for manage_pages permission. Is there any way to do so ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> A Page Access Token is required for all methods.

Since you can only get a Page Token for Pages you manage, there is no way to subscribe a Page to an App without managing it.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps

Comment: I Tried to do following:
- I am the admin of the app. However my app can still not ask for manage pages permission as not yet approved by FB team
- I am the admin of the page
- Now I tried to access my application and I gave the required permissions(i.e. manage pages)
- I got the response as {success : true} to my post request

But when I am doing a get request to /pageId/subscribed_apps, I am getting no object in my response object.

Comment: you do not need approval. you only need to get permissions reviewed if you want to make your app available to other users, not just you.

Comment: the question was about configuring webhooks without manage_pages, which is not possible. about how to deal with webhooks in general is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks - i am not sure what you expect with a get request to subscribed_apps, you did not subscribe yet, right? anyway, read the webhooks tocs and follow the steps carefully.

Comment: Ya my question is to manage public information available on a facebook page via webhook. I have heard of some app-whitelisted concept, which do not required manage_pages permissions. But I am not sure if there is any such thing, as I couldn't find... ??? @luschn

Comment: no, there is no such thing with webhooks. you would need to create a cron job and get the feed manually instead, if you don´t own the page.